# Missing $ inserted. Extra }, or forgotten $. Missing } inserted

Tags: math-mode

I know this gets asked pretty often but I can not find my error. And since the code renders just fine I am really at odds here.

```
\begin{equation} 
 \frac{\Delta {f}}{f} = -\frac{\pi\textrm{r^3}}{W} \frac{\epsilon_r-1}{\epsilon_r+2}\epsilon_0{|{E_0}^2|}
 \label{eq. 5}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for wanting “r” in upright type? I see none.

Comment: My supervisor. End of story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\textrm{...}` command converts the contents of command to text mode, consequently `r^3` cannot work. Instead it you should use `\marthrm{r^3}` as suggested @Sebastiano in his answer (+1) or better and more correct `\mathrm{r}^3` as suggested @GuM in his comment. However, I wonder why you like to write variable in `roman` shape. They are usually written in italic shape. So to my opinion is better write your equation as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert} % new, it better align vertical bars

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\Delta{f}}{f} 
    = - \frac{\pi r^3}{W} 
        \frac{\epsilon_r - 1}{\epsilon_r + 2}\epsilon_0 \abs*{E_0^2}
 \label{eq. 5}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

If you persist to use upshape `r`, than you need to be consistent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\Delta{f}}{f} 
    = - \frac{\pi \mathrm{r}^3}{W} 
        \frac{\epsilon_{\mathrm{r}} - 1}{\epsilon_{\mathrm{r}} + 2}\epsilon_0 \abs*{E_0^2}
 \label{eq. 5}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Often it is very important to put a complete code starting from `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}`. There are two mistakes: `\label{eq.5}` into the formula e when you use a formula the correct syntax is: `\mathrm` instead of `\textrm`. After my humble suggestion:
use `\epsilon_{0}` instead of `\epsilon_0`, it is very important for the future.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}\label{eq.5}
\begin{equation} 
 \frac{\Delta {f}}{f} = -\frac{\pi\mathrm{r^3}}{W} \frac{\epsilon_r-1}{\epsilon_r+2}\epsilon_0{|{E_0}^2|}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I find `\mathrm{r}^3` more elegant…

Comment: @GuM But my English language is horrible :-(...ahhahaha.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. I can only accept one answer. Sorry :(.

Comment: @julesc Don't worry I'm very happy to help you a bit. The Zarko's answer is the best.